# How far can you get video without a VTX antenna?

Tags: video-transmitters, antenna, analog-fpv-system, soldering, distance-limit

My VTX antenna connector got ripped off the VTX, and I don't know if I fixed it properly or not since the VTX sends video without an antenna plugged in.

Answer (score 5):

First off, DO NOT power up the quad without a VTX antenna as this can damage the VTX.

And to actually answer your question, it varies. Depending on the quality of the VTX and the power output, you may find you get a decent signal for a small distance, however the signal will be significantly weaker than if you had an antenna and penetration will not be good.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I know if my antenna is actually connected to the VTX? I have an Eachine mini VTX from the wizard x220.

Comment: @Vichot the simplest way would simply be to do a range test, however that would involve powering up the VTX so you may damage it. The best way in my opinion would be to check continuity between the connector and the board - is it an MMCX or U.FL connector you had to replace?

Comment: I will test it but I am buying another VTX today anyways, it was just to know so I don't have to wait another month to get back in to the air, since I am going to replace it I don´t really care if it gets powerd with out the antenna. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Vichot you’re welcome. Best of luck!

Comment: Also important to note that continuity isn't necessarily required for an antenna to somewhat function (and also limit impedance to non-damaging levels). Putting the contacts _really close_ to each other is effectively connecting them at these frequencies